# How to delete \xa0 symbol from all dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a data frame with the 2011 census (Chile) information. In some columns names and some variable values, I have \xa0 symbol and is trouble to call some parts of data frames. My code is the following:

```py
import numpy as numpy                    
import pandas as pd                      
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sn
#READ AND SAVE EACH DATA SET IN A DATA FRAME
data_2011 = pd.read_csv("2011.csv")
#SHOW FIRST 5 ROWS
print(data_2011.head())
```

Doing this got the following output:
[image]

This far, everything is right, but when I want to see the column names using:

```py
print("ATRIBUTOS DATOS CENSO 2011",list(data_2011))
```

I got the following ouput:
[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use `replace`?

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your data that's not an image?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```py
import re

inputarray = re.sub(r'\s', data_2011).split(",')
```